# How to use spatial transformer to crop the image in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torch

the paper of the spatial transformer network claims that it can be used to crop the image.

Given the crop region (top_left, bottom_right)=(x1,y1,x2,y2), how to interpret the region as a transformation matrix and crop the image in pytorch?

Here is a introduction about the spatial transformer network in torch (http://torch.ch/blog/2015/09/07/spatial_transformers.html), in the introduction, it visualize the bounding box where the transformer look at, How can we determine the bounding box given the transformation matrix?

[Edit]

I just found out the answer to the first question [given the crop region, find out a transformation matrix]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this tutorial? https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/spatial_transformer_tutorial.html

Comment: yup. But I have no idea of the relationship between crop and stn. How to formulate a transformation matrix given a crop region?

Comment: in addition, the image after the spatial transformer network always contain black region in the official tutorial. but it does not have the black region in the tutorial link I provide

Comment: @alec.tu a black region means your transformation is out of bounds for your given output size. Make sure that the position and scale you use in the transformation are in the correct ranges (e.g -0.5 to 0.5 for translation when reducing the output size by half)

Answer (score 0):

The image in the original post already provides a good answer, but it might be useful to provide some code.

Importantly, this method should retain gradients correctly. In my case I have a batch of y,x values that represent the center of the crop position (in the range [-1,1]). As for the values `a` and `b`, which are scale x and y values for the transformation, in my case I used `0.5` for each in combination with a smaller output size (half in width and height) to retain the original scale, i.e. to crop. You can use `1` to have no scale changes, but then there would be no cropping.

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F

def crop_to_affine_matrix(t):
    'Turns (N,2) translate values into (N,2,3) affine transformation matrix'
    t = t.reshape(-1,1,2,1).flip(2) # flip x,y order to y,x
    t = F.pad(t, (2,0,0,0)).squeeze(1)
    t[:,0,0] = a
    t[:,1,1] = b
    return t

t = torch.zeros(5,2) # center crop positions for batch size 5
F.affine_grid(crop_to_affine_matrix(t), outsize)
```